# Checking for error level in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that runs on Windows which calls a Java class and this Java class does something and returns either 0 or -1. Here it is:

```
@echo off
java -cp wcs-all-1.3.jar;scala-library.jar;health-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.test.healthtest.ServerHealthTest localhost 9999
set exitCode=%ERRORLEVEL%
if not %exitCode% 0 goto doFail
:doFail 
  echo %exitCode%
  call ../stop
  call ../start
```

When I run this however, I get the following message printed on the console. My Java program actually returns -1 which means that my batch file should actually call two other batch files, but I see the following as the last line:

```
0 was unexpected at this time.
```

Any ideas as to what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the final working version of the batch file:

```
@echo off
java -cp wcs-all-1.3.jar;scala-library.jar;health-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.test.healthtest.ServerHealthTest localhost 9000
set exitCode=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %exitCode%==0 echo "Server healthy! Not restarting"
if not %exitCode%==0 (
  call ../stop
  call ../start
)
```